# How to reduce space before minipage

Tags: vertical-alignment, minipage

Question: I want to reduce the extra space between the first line of an answer and the start of minipage.

This is what I have done so far:

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=1 in,bottom=1 in,left=0.7 in,right=0.7 in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[misc]{ifsym}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\makeatother
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\setlength{\parskip}{1ex}
\begin{document}
\textbf{Answer:}~Let the points are $A\,\left(x_1 , x_2\right)$, $B\,\left(y_1 , y_2\right)$ and $C\,\left(z_1 , z_2\right)$.

 \begin{minipage}[b]{.5\textwidth}
    \begin{flalign*}
        \rightarrow AB^2&=&\\
        &=&\\
        \therefore\;AB&=&   
    \end{flalign*}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
    \begin{flalign*}
        \rightarrow BC^2&=&\\
        &=&\\
        \therefore\;BC&=&
    \end{flalign*}  
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your set-up there is a `\parskip` before the `minipage` and once the minipage starts there is an `\abovedisplayskip` at the top each set of equations.  You can undo either of these vertical spaces by issuing `\vspace{-\parskip}` or `\vspace{-\abovedisplayskip}` just before the minipage.  Which one you choose is up to what spacing you wish to have:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage[a4paper,top=1 in,bottom=1 in,left=0.7 in,right=0.7 in]{geometry}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[misc]{ifsym}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\setlength{\parskip}{1ex}

\begin{document}
\textbf{Answer:} Let the points be $A = (x_1 , x_2)$, $B = (y_1 ,
y_2)$ and $C = (z_1 , z_2)$.  Remove \verb+\parskip+.

\vspace{-\parskip}
\begin{minipage}[b]{.5\textwidth}
    \begin{flalign*}
        \rightarrow AB^2&=&\\
        &=&\\
        \therefore\;AB&=&
    \end{flalign*}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
    \begin{flalign*}
        \rightarrow BC^2&=&\\
        &=&\\
        \therefore\;BC&=&
    \end{flalign*}
\end{minipage}

\textbf{Answer:} Let the points be $A = (x_1 , x_2)$, $B = (y_1 ,
y_2)$ and $C = (z_1 , z_2)$.  Remove \verb+\abovedisplayskip+.

\vspace{-\abovedisplayskip}
\begin{minipage}[b]{.5\textwidth}
    \begin{flalign*}
        \rightarrow AB^2&=&\\
        &=&\\
        \therefore\;AB&=&
    \end{flalign*}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
    \begin{flalign*}
        \rightarrow BC^2&=&\\
        &=&\\
        \therefore\;BC&=&
    \end{flalign*}
\end{minipage}

\textbf{Answer:} Let the points be $A = (x_1 , x_2)$, $B = (y_1 ,
y_2)$ and $C = (z_1 , z_2)$.  Remove nothing.

\begin{minipage}[b]{.5\textwidth}
    \begin{flalign*}
        \rightarrow AB^2&=&\\
        &=&\\
        \therefore\;AB&=&
    \end{flalign*}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
    \begin{flalign*}
        \rightarrow BC^2&=&\\
        &=&\\
        \therefore\;BC&=&
    \end{flalign*}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `\vspace{-...}` with a negative distance before `\begin{minipage}...`
command as in

```
\textbf{Answer:}~Let the points are $A\,\left(x_1 , x_2\right)$, $B\,\left(y_1 , y_2\right)$ and $C\,\left(z_1 , z_2\right)$.

\vspace{-4ex}
\begin{minipage}[b]{.5\textwidth}
```

Be sure to leave a blank line before the `\vspace` command though.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Thank you for your answer but, generally, it's better to reply with a complete compilable [example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).