# Bad vertical spacing in multicol

Tags: vertical-alignment, multicol

## Issue

First, I'm sorry: I didn't manage to produce a MWE. I hope some of you will still be able to help.

I use the `multicol` package to create list of exercises. An `exercise` is an environment which is within a `minipage` (to prevent column breaks). Something like

```
\newenvironment{exo}
{\begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}}
{\end{minipage}}
```

Quite often, the first exercise of a new column is not aligned with the top of the column:

[image]

## Idea 1

I have noticed that putting `\setlength{\topskip}{0pt}` helps a lot but still, it is not perfectly aligned.

[image]

## Idea 2

Quite surprisingly, I change `\begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}` to `\begin{minipage}{0.97\columnwidth}` (in the current example), the issue disappears:

[image]

## Idea 3

If I delete the newlines between two `exercise` environments (in the source), the problem disappears but that makes the source file less readable:

```
\begin{exercise}
bla bla bla
\end{exercise}
\begin{exercise}
bla bla bla
\end{exercise}
```

## Question

So, do you have any hint?

## File

The source files (not MWE at all) are there https://we.tl/Hbap24qlw2

Comment: not a solution, but to make the source more readable, insert a line with only `%` at the beginning.  this will be ignored (it's a comment), but will give some visual space where it's wanted.

Comment: `aligned` environment may be useful. [https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111891/aligned-environment-of-amsmath-vs-array-environment](http://alingn%20environment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem doesn't come from the `multicol` environment, it comes from the `minipage` environment that adds a space before.

The removal of the space located before the minipage environment is given in this response: [How to reduce space before minipage](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/332683/138900)

> You can undo either of these vertical spaces by issuing
>   `\vspace{-\parskip}` or `\vspace{-\abovedisplayskip}` just before the
>   minipage.

Just delete the space before the minipage environment, which is before `begin{exo}`:

```
\vspace{-\abovedisplayskip}
\vspace{-\parskip}
\begin{exo} 
Vous voulez acheter un billet de loterie. Le buraliste,
logicien à ses heures perdues, vous en présente cinq numérotés de 1
à 5, et vous déclare :
\begin{itemize}
 \item si 5 est perdant, alors 1 est gagnant ;  
\item si 4 est perdant, alors 2 est gagnant ;    
 \item si 3 est perdant, alors 5 aussi ;    
 \item si 1 est gagnant, alors 2 aussi ;    
 \item si 3 est gagnant, alors 4 est perdant.
\end{itemize}
%\noindent 
Quel billet choisissez-vous ?

\end{exo}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. But I had to increase the space after `exo` so that two exercises don't overlap.

Comment: This code should only be placed before `exo` environments that require it as I did in the example (and it works very well). But if you want to integrate it in the `exo` environment code, you will have to add an equivalent spacing at the end of the environment.

Comment: Yep, that’s what I did.

Comment: Just to say, the space above `minipage` is not always added when a new column is started.

Comment: Interesting, have you found under what conditions this space is added?

Comment: No, unfortunately...